# Racket lang: access element in list

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Give a single function to access the element a in the list L.

```
(define L '(1 2 (a 3 4 5)))
```

Following the form (define id expr) which binds id to the result of expression I have tried the following:

```
(define L '(1 2 (a 3 4 5) (car(cdr L))))
```

cdr accesses the tail of the list, i.e. a 3 4 5, if I am not mistaken, and then I apply car on the tail to access the head of the list, i.e a. However, it is not working on DrRacket IDE.

Comment: "it's not working" is not a helpful problem description. Please [edit] your question and describe exactly what happens and what you expected to happen instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to do this:

```
(define L '(1 2 (a 3 4 5)))

(car (car (cdr (cdr L))))
=> 'a
```

Which can also be written as:

```
(caaddr L)
=> 'a
```

Answer (score 2):

You included the `(car(cdr L))` part inside the list `L`.

```
> (define L '(1 2 (a 3 4 5) (car(cdr L))))
> L
(list 1 2 (list 'a 3 4 5) (list 'car (list 'cdr 'L))) ;; oh no
```

But that still doesn't extract the `'a` because you need to access `car` of the inner list:

```
(define L '(1 2 (a 3 4 5)))
(car (car (cdr (cdr L))))
;; or (caaddr L)
```